# Do Rust comments increase binary size?

Tags: rust, compiler-optimization, rust-cargo

Do regular [comments](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/book/ch03-04-comments.html#comments) or [Documentation Comments](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch14-02-publishing-to-crates-io.html#making-useful-documentation-comments) affect the final size of Rust binaries?

My guess is that while doc comments in a library crate would result in larger download size from [crates.io](https://crates.io), but comments are stripped at compile time.

Maybe it is a silly question but curiosity has gotten the better of me and I have not found an answer in the rust book, online, or in the [Rust GitHub repo](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Both normal comments and doc comments are not compiled to machine code. They can at most increase compilation time (and not significantly, especially normal comments since they're stripped at parsing and not keeped for later).